# How can I run TypeScript tests (example.test.ts) with Jest?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have installed `@types/jest` with npm, which resolves the autocomplete problems, but I  can't find a solution for compatibility.

When I run tests, I get the error:

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token
```

Comment: Probably your Jest configuration is wrong, or you have error in test file, please share your code.

Comment: There is also this thing: [ts-jest](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest)

Comment: @KamilNaja I haven't done any type of configuration, just ran the `npm install jest --save-dev --exact`, after that, I ran `npm install @types/jest --save-dev --exact`

Comment: @marsibarsi I'll take a look, is it a npm package?

Comment: Maybe you need special Jest version for ts. I think, that Jest find file format, that cannot understand and this is reason of fail. Please try Jest-ts https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/user/config/

Comment: I usually just point jest at the output of compiled .js files, and use the source-map-support modules with source maps output during compilation; its easier than dealing with ts-jest imo.

Comment: ok guys, I'll take a look when I have time. Thanks! :)

Comment: `Jest` provides a `TypeScript` guide [in the docs here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-typescript)

Comment: Done! I instaled ts-jest and used 

`"jest": {
    "preset": "ts-jest"
  },`  

to configure jest mode.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install jest - `npm install jest --save-dev --exact`
2. Install @types/jest for jest auto complete in code editor - `npm install @types/jest --save-dev --exact`
3. Install ts-jest - `npm install ts-jest --save-dev --exact`
4. Added jest config code to package.json

   ```
   "jest": {
      "preset": "ts-jest"
   },
   ```
5. Added test script

   ```
   "test":"jest",
   ```
6. Done

Credits:

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/5736236/kamil-naja
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/11197798/marsibarsi

More info about:

- [ts-jest presets](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/user/config/)
- [ts-jest GitHub](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest)

Comment: Any idea how to then run a specific test or testfile? The same syntax doesn't work for ts-jest.